# Time zone in Power Automate

Tags: time, timezone, sharepoint-online, power-automate, power-platform

I'm using **ConvertTimeZone** function in power automate to convert from UTC to a certain time zone. The only conversion that has passed is from **UTC** to **Eastern Standard Time**:

```
convertTimeZone(triggerOutputs()?['body/Maintenance_x0020_Window'],'UTC','Eastern Standard Time','dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm tt')
```

Next I need to convert to the time zone in London - **Greenwich Mean Time/GMT** and to Lyon, Rhône, France time zone **Central European Summer Time/CEST** but i get this error:
**the value provided for the time zone id 'Central European Summer Time' was not valid.**

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The answer’s there but this is all in doco … https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones?view=windows-11

Comment: @Skin Sure there are "Microsoft timezones" listed in the doc you linked, with values like "Central European Time" and "Central Europe Time", but without knowing the difference between those two that documentation is useless. It certainly wouldn't have helped to determine that "Romance Standard Time" was appropriate. The documentation is low quality, as is Microsoft's approach of making up timezones without even mapping them to ISO timezones.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the `convertTimeZone` function expects a Windows time zone identifier. For your requested zones, the IDs are:

- `"Eastern Standard Time"` - for the Eastern time zone of US & Canada inclusive of both EST and EDT
- `"GMT Standard Time"` - for Great Britain, inclusive of both GMT and BST
- `"Romance Standard Time"` - for France and several other European countries, inclusive of both CET and CEST

Yes - the names are confusing.  You can read more about this and see ways to get the entire list of zone names by reading the subsection titled *"The Microsoft Windows Time Zone Database"* within the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).